# Need to create regular expression for one file having sentence

Tags: perl

```
L02    TIME DEPOSITS                             489,26,45,422.92                                                   
L18    DRAFTS ACCOUNT (IF CREDIT)                10,063.00           10,063.00                                                
L21    SBI BILLS ACCOUNT (CONTRA) A18                              37,51,432.00 
A12A   DEMAND LOANS                                               4,39,13,597.30
```

These are the lines I have in my file I want to extract the amounts from each line which starts with either (L or A) and store into a variable.

This  is what I have written

```
pattern =/[A-Z]\w+\s*([\d,.]*)\s*([\d,.])*/g
$first = $1;
$second= $2;
```

Comment: I edited your question. Please don't say "_Please help_" and such.  You have asked by posting a question.

Comment: Put expected output in your question. I don't see how  _first_ and _second_ amounts are separated in your input data except for the second line.

Comment: Look at [mcve] for more info how to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is looking for a string of `\w` and *then* spaces in the middle so it cannot match multiple words. The last `*` should be inside the parenthesis, like the first one (but see below). The `[A-Z]` matches *any* block capital while you say that you want `A` or `L`, so use `[AL]` instead.

```
my @amounts = $string =~ /^[AL]\w+ \s+ [A-Za-z ]* ([\d,.]*)/xg;
```

You don't want to literally repeat the pattern with `*` quantifier in order to account for a variable number of occurrences. What if 2 becomes 3  when requirements change? Four? Instead, you can capture all matches in an array and get exactly as many as there are.

The `/x` allows us to use spaces inside for readability.

---

Here is another approach, which is more flexible.

You need a pattern containing any of digit, `,` (comma), `.` (period) -- and which is only such in the string. You want this only on lines that start with `A` or `L`.

So skip lines which do not start with `A` or `L`, then match only the needed pattern.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $filename = '...';
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";

while (<$fh>)
{
    next unless /^[AL]/;   # skip if the line doesn't start with A or L

    my @amounts = $_ =~ /\b ([\d,.]+) \b/xg;

    print "@amounts\n" if @amounts;
}
close $fh;
```

Here you need to specify `\b`, the *word boundary*.  Otherwise `02` in `L02` is matched, for example.

With no matches the array is empty so we test, to not print empty lines. Adjust as suitable.

---

The next step in reducing reliance on regex details and making code more flexible is to [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the line by spaces and process term by term. Then adjustments are far easier and changes can be absorded.

For example, this helps with the change in data mentioned in a comment -- what if there is a date? The above regex would match the numeric parts, while the first one would just break down.

With a loop over fields on each line we can just skip the date, `next if /\d{4}-\d{2}/;`

Comment: Hi Zdim.. How to add in your pattern that sentence should start with L or A as i am reading file line by line. As not all lines are starting with A or L and there are many lines where data is not there  which i want to capture

Comment: @Volverine I just added the anchor (but it should work without it as well.)

Comment: there are multiple lines and the data which i am looking always in the line which starts with A or L ...so i want to first look for then store ....how to add ^A|^L before word boundary

Comment: @Volverine  In the second solution you don't have to -- you first skip lines that do not start with that.  So you only work with lines that start with `A` or `L`.  The first solution has that built into the regex, `/^[A,L].../` -- lines which _do not_ start with it won't match.

Comment: Thanks Zdim for your help

Comment: what is the same  line contains                                                            A30BZ  ADD INTEREST SUBVENTION RECEIVABLE FOR PROMPT PAYING FARMERS - 2015-16                53,502.00                     in this same line contains 2015-16 which i dont want

Comment: @Volverine Heh, that's different data.  That's the thing with regex -- it is sensitive to detail, and would have to be modified to somehow exclude dates (otherwise the pattern would match the numeric part of the date).  Or, better, just split the string by spaces, which returns an array -- then iterate over it nicely matching term by term.  Then you can skip dates specifically, `next if /\d{4}-\d{2}/;`

Comment: Don't put comma between L and A. Just `[AL]`.

Comment: @Volverine  Please note the update -- to specify `A` or `L` one needs `[AL]`, of course.  The comma that I had in between was allowing a comma as well.  It worked for your data but it was wrong.